# Debugging not work on Nougat emulator, but works on real KitKat device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'll debug my application on a simulated Android Nougat *(7.0)* device. I've enabeld the developers settings but I've got the message

> WatchFriends has stopped

[image]

Here is a part of the console output:

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 4855 (JDWP)

[ 01-25 13:01:56.449  1228: 1228 W/         ]
debuggerd: handling request: pid=4848 uid=10071 gid=10071 tid=4855
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8611', transport: 'socket'
```

If I just run the application without debugging, I've no problems or errors. What is the problem I've got? There is no error printed in the console of Android Studio.

Is there a setting that I must enable in the developer settings?

I've tried also on a real Android KitKat *(4.4)* device to debug my application and this will hit all the breakpoints without a problem.

**Update:** I've also tried on an Marshmallow *(6.0)* emulator and debugging works fine.

I'm working with Android Studio 2.2.2

Comment: @Pauwulyn : did u find any solution? I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

*Update:I founded that there was two activity xml files, one named activity.xml and the other was v23/activity.xml , I removed the second one from its path to the recycle bin and it worked finally.

I got this exact problem after adding admob to my app , I am a begginer I cant figure out what really is the problem in the code ..hope somebody will help.
Here is the code in the attached pictures.
[1st,2nd....5th step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4DLN.jpg)

[last step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PYek.jpg)